Raw http/2 client
I'm writing a raw HTTP/2 client on rust, I encountered a problem: Bad Request 400.
Frames seem to encode correctly, and my server also decodes and receives correctly, but Google and other sites give me an error 400.
Code:
extern crate bytes;

use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

use hpack::Encoder;
use bytes::{Bytes, BytesMut};

use boring::ssl::{ConnectConfiguration, SslConnector, SslMethod};

use std::error::Error;
use std::net::ToSocketAddrs;
use std::io::Write;

use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

use tokio_boring::connect;


fn encode_frame(frame_type: u8, flags: u8, stream_id: u32, payload: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let payload_length = payload.len() as u32;

    let mut frame = Vec::new();

    // Encoding frame length
    frame.push(((payload_length >> 16) & 0xFF) as u8);
    frame.push(((payload_length >> 8) & 0xFF) as u8);
    frame.push((payload_length & 0xFF) as u8);

    // Frame type and flags
    frame.push(frame_type);
    frame.push(flags);

    // Stream ID (big-endian)
    frame.push(((stream_id >> 24) & 0xFF) as u8);
    frame.push(((stream_id >> 16) & 0xFF) as u8);
    frame.push(((stream_id >> 8) & 0xFF) as u8);
    frame.push((stream_id & 0xFF) as u8);

    // Add payload to frame
    frame.extend_from_slice(&payload);

    frame
}

fn encode_settings_frame(settings: &[(u16, u32)]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut payload = Vec::new();

    for &(identifier, value) in settings {
        payload.push((identifier >> 8) as u8);
        payload.push((identifier & 0xFF) as u8);
        payload.push((value >> 24) as u8);
        payload.push((value >> 16) as u8);
        payload.push((value >> 8) as u8);
        payload.push((value & 0xFF) as u8);
    }

    payload
}


fn encode_windows_update_frame(increment: u32) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut payload = Vec::new();

    payload.push((increment >> 24) as u8);
    payload.push((increment >> 16) as u8);
    payload.push((increment >> 8) as u8);
    payload.push((increment & 0xFF) as u8);

    payload
}


fn encode_headers_frame(headers: Vec<(&str, &str)>, stream_id: u32) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut encoder = Encoder::new();

    let byte_headers: Vec<(&[u8], &[u8])> = headers.iter().map(|(name, value)| (name.as_bytes(), value.as_bytes())).collect();

    let encoded_headers = encoder.encode(byte_headers);

    let flags = 0x04;

    encode_frame(0x01, 0x04, stream_id, encoded_headers)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let url_t = "www.google.com";
    let addr = format!("{}:443", url_t).to_socket_addrs()?.next().unwrap();
    let tcp = TcpStream::connect(&addr).await?;

    let cipher_list = "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA";
    let mut builder = SslConnector::builder(SslMethod::tls())?;
    builder.set_verify(boring::ssl::SslVerifyMode::NONE);
    builder.set_grease_enabled(true);
    builder.enable_ocsp_stapling();
    builder.set_cipher_list(&cipher_list)?;
    builder.set_alpn_protos(b"\x02h2")?;
    builder.enable_signed_cert_timestamps();
    let connector = builder.build();

    let mut connect_config = connector.configure()?;
    connect_config.set_verify_hostname(false);

    let mut res = tokio_boring::connect(connect_config, url_t, tcp).await;
    let mut tls = res.unwrap();

    let request = "PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n";
    tls.write_all(request.as_bytes()).await?;

    let settings = [
        (0x03, 100),
        (0x04, 2097152),
        (0x02, 0)
    ];

    let settings_payload = encode_settings_frame(&settings);
    let settings_frame = encode_frame(0x04, 0x00, 0, settings_payload);
    tls.write_all(&settings_frame).await?;

    // sending window_update
    let window_update_payload = encode_windows_update_frame(10485760);
    let window_update_frame = encode_frame(0x08, 0x00, 0, window_update_payload);
    tls.write_all(&window_update_frame).await?;

    let headers = vec![
        (":method", "GET"),
        (":scheme", "https"),
        (":path", "/"),
        (":authority", url_t),
        ("user-agent", "test/1.0"),
    ];
    
    let headers_frame = encode_headers_frame(headers, 1);

    tls.write_all(&headers_frame).await?;

    let mut response = String::new();
    tls.read_to_string(&mut response).await?;
    println!("{}", response);

    let _ = tls.shutdown();

    Ok(())
}

Tried removing and adding ALPN, "h2". If you leave ALPN = h2, there will be no response from the server and it will not count it, and if you remove it, it will give Bad Request 400.

Probably a good idea to not test against google, but instead something local/more predictable just in case you're running into bot detection issues. You might also get better logs that way.

You definitely need ALPN. Without ALPN h2 the request will be interpreted as HTTP/1, resulting in the 400 Bad request you see.

@Evert I tested on a local server that receives and decodes all HTTP/2 frames and it successfully received and decoded all frames including headers. But for some reason when I tested on my cloudflare site, it did not show logs, although the same code on nodejs successfully sent requests.

@user24806184: And your local server for testing is some third party implementation or your own?

@SteffenUllrich my own, ssl server writed on golang

@user24806184: I recommend that you try against some third party implementation, like nginx or similar. Trying only against your own implementation has the risk of having the same systematic implementation errors.
